# Does Google Analytics online status have an effect?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've setup and installed Google Analytics as per the Google instructions. The problem is that my site url looks like this - **services.foo.com/testing**.

There are two websites on our web server

- foo (large corporate website)
- foo.services (small websites)

When I check the Tracking Code Status within the Google Admin UI, I see "**Tracker Not Installed**".

When I check the tracker javascript code I can see

```
ga('create', '....', 'foo.com');
```

So I assume that Google is just checking against the top most site in the URL, and not my services sub domain.

Is there anyway to point the tracker towards the sub domain??

Note: I don't want to add the tracker code to the corporate website yet, as we are still evaluating analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one top-level domain and one sub-domain, correct?

- foo.com (top-level)
- services.foo.com (sub-domain of
  top-level)

If this is the case, then you only need to include the tracking code that Universal Analytics gives you on every page of both foo.com and services.foo.com.

That code should look something like this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'foo.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

By default, Universal Analytics does not require any additional configuration for tracking users across sub-domains - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain (see the gray note section towards the top of the page).

Hope this helps.